# Magnetic field strength vs flux density

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, field-theory

What's the actual difference?

I've been told that they're the same thing; however, I seem to remember reading somewhere that where are different types of measures for field strength, denoted by the letters B and I think 2 others.

Answer (score 0):

It's the "old" way of speaking. If you are learning E&M now, most modern books will use SI units and the $\mathbf E, \mathbf B, \mathbf D, \mathbf H $ fields.

Nowadays, we call $\mathbf B$ the magnetic field and $\mathbf H $ just the "H field". In the older books, they call $\mathbf H $ the magnetic field, and $\mathbf B $ the magnetic flux density or something of that sort.